# Hide Hibernate session handling from business logic

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose I have an entity "Parent" which holds a list of "Child" objects.

In Java this looks like this:

```
public class ParentEntity implements Parent {
   protected int id;
   @Override
   public int getId() { return id; }
   @Override
   public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

   protected List<Child> children;
   @Override
   public List<Child> getChildren() { return children; }
   @Override
   public void setChildren(List<Child> children) { this.children = children; }

   @Override
   public void save() {
      // Do some Hibernate "save" magic here...
   }

   public static Parent getById(int id) {
      Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      Parent entity = (Parent) session.get(ParentEntity.class, id);
      session.close();
      return entity;
   }
}
```

My business logic class shall only work with the interface class, like this:

```
public class BusinessLogic {
   public void doSomething() {
      Parent parent = ParentEntity.getById(1);
      for (Child c : parent.getChildren())
         System.out.println("I love my daddy.");
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because the parent's children do not get loaded and the loop crashes with a NullPointerException.

## 1. Approach "Eager Loading"

There are two problems with this approach. Even though in the XML I wrote "lazy='false'" Hibernate seems to ignore this.
Secondly, eager loading is not desirable in my case since we could have hundreds of children, potentially.

## 2. Approach "Load/Initialize on 'GET'"

```
@Override
public List<Child> getChildren()
{
   if (!Hibernate.isInitialized(children)) {
      Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      Hibernate.initialize(children);
      session.close();
   }
   return children;
}
```

This doesn't work either because I get an exception saying that the collection is not linked to a session. The session which was used to load the parent entity was closed, previously.

**What do you suggest is the 'best practice' solution here? I really don't want to mess with Hibernate sessions in my business logic.**

Comment: Could you explain why eager loading is not an option? You could even use a custom query for your concrete use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can use a query-object or a custom query and fetch all children in the scenarios you really need them (search for `left join fetch`), for a few thousand objects this might work.

However if the amount of records could reach millions you are running most likely into memory issues, then you should think about a shared cache, retrieving the data on a page by page basis Just search for n+1 and hibernate you will find plenty of discussions around this topic.

The simplest **hack** I can think of:

```
public static Parent getParentWithChildrenById(int id) {
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  Parent entity = (Parent) session.get(ParentEntity.class, id);
  Hibernate.initialize(entity.children);
  session.close();
  return entity;
}
```

*Side-note:* Having the data access logic in you domain layer is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I've always allowed Spring and JPA to manage my Hibernate sessions, so most of the painful boilerplate code disappears at that point.  But you still have to call `entity.getChildren().size()` (or something similar) before you exit the data layer call where the session is opened, to force Hibernate to do the retrieval while there's still a session to use.